# Check $http.post data on the server side in rest framework

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to check the incoming json data which comes to the rest framework through a post method? I hava a view defined as below:

```
class StudentAcademicProgramList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        student_academic_program = Student_academic_program.objects.filter(student=29722)
        serialized_Student_academic_program = StudentAcademicProgramSerializer(student_academic_program, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_Student_academic_program.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = StudentAcademicProgramSerializer(data = request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class StudentAcademicProgramDetail(APIView):
    def get_objects(self, pk):
    try:
        return Student_academic_program.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Student_academic_program.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    student_academic_program = self.get_objects(pk)
        serialized_Student_academic_program = StudentAcademicProgramSerializer(student_academic_program)
        return Response(serialized_Student_academic_program.data)
```

Whenever I am sending data using the $http.post from the front end, it is throwing me the 400 Error. How do I check what data I am receiving in the server?

Answer (score 0):

you can print request.DATA['fieldname'] from serializer, before checking if your serializer approves new post.